# Spark - Evaluation Issue

Tags: apache-spark, evaluation, anomaly-detection

I am trying to evaluate a model i have created. the model gives me in output, a list of ids and their corespondant error construction (a score) and the ids are sorted depending on this score. let's say the higher the score the more the id is suspicious.

Example:

```
ids: t4, c1, s3, d5, a2, ...
score: 18, 15, 13, 5, 2, ...
```

Also, I have another list which contains the real suspicious ids.

```
suspicious: c1,d5
```

my goal is to be able to say that x% of the ids in my suspicious list are at top y% in the score list.

any ideas please ? and implementation in spark would be generous from you !

Answer (score 0):

here is what i did, using pandas dataframe:

- I created a dataframes df that contains all data, and loaded the suspicious data into a serie.
- added anothe column into df, that I named label. the label of the record is based wither id exist in suspicious or not
- with this final dataframe (id, score, label), I was able to make counts based on the label, and be able to have statement such as the one in the question.